# Can not start new activity from alertdialog onclicklistener when activitygroup is used

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-alertdialog, activitygroup

I simply have 2 tabs and used [Experience - Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) as reference.
My class Architecture is like this:
          **MainActivity**  extends TabActivity
               1.**TabGroup1Activity** extends TabGroupActivity (TabGroupActivity-class implemented from above reference)
  1.i. **Tab1Activity** extends MapActivity (which has multiple marker)
2.**TabGroup2Activity** extends TabGroupActivity
2.i. **Tab2Activity**

In second tab (Tab2Activity) i show the google map which has multiple markers. On Taping the marker I showed the alertdialog with More Info option.
Onclicking the More Info Option i have to start new activity without loosing tabs at bottom.

where is the error i dont know ??

**MapItemizedOverlay.java**

```
public class InformationItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;
Activity parentContext;

public InformationItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context,
        Activity parent) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

    mContext = context;
    parentContext = parent;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(parentContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setPositiveButton("More Info..",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent test = new Intent(parentContext,
                            AboutActivity.class);
                    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) parentContext;
                    parentActivity
                            .startChildActivity("AboutActivity", test);
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
    return true;

}
}
```

When i try with above code, error gives when i click the More Info button at alertdialog.
When i remove the alertdialog and write the following code, it works fine, opens new activity in the same tab:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

                    Intent test = new Intent(parentContext,
                            AboutActivity.class);
                    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) parentContext;
                    parentActivity
                            .startChildActivity("AboutActivity", test);
                }
            });

    return true;

}
```

How can i make it work to open new activity when i click the More Info button at alertdialog ??
Help !!

> 04-05 17:42:02.171: W/dalvikvm(2631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bbs.MainActivity
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.bbs1.InformationItemizedOverlay$1.onClick(InformationItemizedOverlay.java:63)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   04-05 17:42:02.171: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you send the logcat error details

Comment: @Nishant just updated with logcat error !!

Comment: What is line 63 in your code? The `TabGroupActivity` cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the `AlertDialogue` on `current UI Thread`. Use `runOnUiThread()` to start the UI Thread.Here is the example:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(parentContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.setPositiveButton("More Info..",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent test = new Intent(parentContext,AboutActivity.class);
  TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) parentContext;
  parentActivity.startChildActivity("AboutActivity", test);
  }
  });
  dialog.show();
 }//run
});//runOnUIThred
```

Comment: I have send you an example. You have to write the code inside the onTap() method

Comment: It says `The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type InformationItemizedOverlay`